# How to append data in an already existing data .txt file in newline or in tab separtion?

Tags: export, data

Say I have an already existing .txt file containing data in the following format.

> $a \qquad b$

Now at different times I will successively have data like `"c,d,e,f,g,h,i"` etc

Now next time as I will have the data `"c"`, I want the data to be appended in the first row with tab separation. That is like this:

> $a \qquad b \qquad c$

And then next time I will have the data `"d"`. So next time what I want is

> $a \qquad b \qquad c$
>
> $d$

and so on.

Though from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416390/exporting-appending-prepending-data-and-text-into-files-mathematica/7417916#7417916), I know how to add data in the newline using `OpenAppend`, but I don't know how to add data in the same line with tab separation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OpenAppend` itself does not cause newlines to be added.  Only the export/write functions do.  If you use [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html), it won't add newlines.

For example,

```
s = OpenAppend["app.txt"]

Do[WriteString[s, "a"], {5}]

Close[s]
```

results in a file containing `aaaaa`.

You can include tabs using `"\t"`.